# How to make navigation bar transparent in horizontal scrollview

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is the view that I am trying to get, but with a transparent navigation bar within `SubView`.
The final version will have additional stuff below the photo, I don't want the navigation bar to block any content when I scroll down. It has something to do with either the horizontal `ScrollView` or the `LazyHStack` but can't figure out a way to make it work, I'll appreciate any help or hints as to why it doesn't work.

```
struct SomeStruct: Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    let value: String
    
    init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
}

struct Root: View {
    
    @State var items = [SomeStruct(value: "photo"),
                         SomeStruct(value: "photo"),
                         SomeStruct(value: "photo")]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        SubView(items: items)
                            .toolbarBackground(.hidden)
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: item.value)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct SubView: View {
    
    @State var items: [SomeStruct]
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        ScrollView {
                            Image(systemName: item.value)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                        }
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width)
                    }
                }
            }
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        }
    }

}
```

I tried adding `.toolbarBackground(.hidden)` to literally every possible location within the layered view, didn't change a thing. I also tried adding

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

to any possible initializer and `.onAppear()` closure.